# Are capabilities per-process or per-thread attributes?

Tags: posix, capabilities

[Documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) says that capabilities are per-thread attributes. Indeed in any

```
/proc/[PID]/task/[LWP]/status
```

we can find capabilities, related to this thread:

```
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

But at the same time similar information about capabilities is located in

```
/proc/[PID]/status
```

So process, obviously has its own capabilities. That confuse me - are capabilities attributes of a process or a thread? And what set is checked by kernel, when some capability-requiring command is performed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capabilities are indeed per-thread, and a thread can change its own capabilities (as allowed by the current capabilities) using [`capset`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/capset.2.html) without affecting other existing threads’ capabilities.

`/proc/[PID]/status` shows the capabilities for the thread matching the pid, or more accurately, the thread group id (which is the process id in Linux).

The kernel always checks the capabilities of the relevant thread.